# Eclipse plugin - Programatically create file from template

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I have a Template as org.eclipse.jface.text.templates.Template:

```
Template template = new Template(name, description, contextTypeId, pattern, true);
```

or better the org.eclipse.cdt.core.model.Template:

```
Template template = new Template(templateString);
```

Or let's say that the template already is in the Preferences -> C/C++ -> Code Style -> Code Templates and I can get it directly from there.

Now I want to create a file from it like how you do in the wizard but programmatically:

```
    IFile mainTestFile = testFolder.getFile(resource.getName() + ".myfile");
    if (!mainTestFile.exists()) {
        mainTestFile.create(template, true, null);
    }
```

Unfortunately it only works for InputStream not for Template.

So how can I programmatically create a file in an eclipse project from a template I have?

Comment: Which `Template` class is this?

Comment: org.eclipse.jface.text.templates.Template;

Comment: What wizard are you talking about? Using a template normally requires a `TemplateContext` and a `TemplateContextType`.

Comment: I don't exactly know how to use it as I haven't found much documentation on this topic. I'm talking like the Eclipse new file wizard which generates a file based on a certain template something like: private void ${name}(){  
    System.out.println("${name}")
} 
But to do it programtically without creating an wizard plugin which uses the eclipse framework. Just define the Template as an object and then use the said object when creating a file programmatically in my eclipse project.

Comment: This is actually quite complex and I can't find a straightforward example in the Eclipse source.

Comment: I also found the org.eclipse.cdt.core.model.Template which I first considered and required only a String as argument. Would it be any easier?

Comment: I have no idea about that as it is part of Eclipse CDT which I don't use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the way I did it might seem a bit counter intuitive but it worked:

First you need a class that extends the CDT NewSourceFileCreationWizardPage. Then overload the createFile method to use a org.eclipse.jface.text.templates.Template that you define yourself. The template code will be sotred in a string which can be obtained from a resource file.

```
        Template myTemplate = new Template("My Template", "My Template for file", "com.my.template.contenttype.contenttype_context", templateString, true);

        MyNewFileWizardPage myTemplateWizard = new MyNewFileWizardPage ();

        mainTestFile = myTemplateWizard.createMyFile(myTemplate, mainTestFile.getLocation(), null);
```

And the custom new file wizard page:

```
class MyNewFileWizardPage extends NewSourceFileCreationWizardPage{

   private ITranslationUnit fNewFileTU = null;

   @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
   public IFile createMyFile(Template template, IPath filePath, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
    if (filePath != null) {
        if (monitor == null)
            monitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
        try {
            fNewFileTU = null;
            IFile newFile = NewSourceFileGenerator.createSourceFile(filePath, true, monitor);
            if (newFile != null) {
                fNewFileTU = (ITranslationUnit) CoreModel.getDefault().create(newFile);
                if (fNewFileTU != null) {
                    String lineDelimiter = StubUtility.getLineDelimiterUsed(fNewFileTU);
                    String content = CodeGeneration.getBodyFileContent(template, fNewFileTU, null, null, lineDelimiter);
                    if (content != null) {
                        fNewFileTU.getBuffer().setContents(content.toCharArray());
                        fNewFileTU.save(monitor, true);
                        return newFile;
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            monitor.done();
        }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then with the created IFile you can modify it further if you want anything changed in it.